# Table with multiple indices and constraints (conditions)

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I want to make a table with following data,

$a_{ij} = b_{ij}$ for $1\le i <j\le n-2$ and $|i-j| \ge 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
n = 7;
Table[If[Abs[i - j] > 2, a[i, j] == b[i, j], Nothing], {i, 1,n - 2}, {j, i+1, n - 2}] // Flatten
(*{a[1, 4] == b[1, 4], a[1, 5] == b[1, 5], a[2, 5] == b[2, 5],a[4, 1] == b[4, 1], a[5, 1] == b[5, 1], a[5, 2] == b[5, 2]}*)
```

Comment: Thanks! How to get only non-zero entries of the table? Otherwise it looks a bit clumsy.

Comment: Without knowing `a,b` it's difficult to distinguish non-zero entries!

Comment: I just meant the trivial `0` or `Null` entries that are appearing without referring to `a` or `b`..

Comment: `Nothing` inside If is what you're looking for. My answer is edited.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for and I understand it too.

Comment: Just need to add the extra condition `i<j` which is part of the original condition `1<= i <j <= n-2`.

Comment: I completed my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
n = 7;
t=Table[a[i, j] == b[i, j], {j, 1,n - 2}, {i, 1,j - 2}]/.{}->Sequence[]
```

giving

```
{{a[1,3]==b[1,3]},
 {a[1,4]==b[1,4],a[2,4]==b[2,4]},
 {a[1,5]==b[1,5],a[2,5]==b[2,5],a[3,5]==b[3,5]}}
```

And you can use `Flatten` on that if you don't want the extra `{}`

Comment: This is great! But I have no clue how it's working! Can you explain that `{}->Sequence[]` part? Also can I generalize this to different conditions, say, `|i-j| >= 5` or something..

Comment: If you try that without the `/.{}->Sequence[]` you will see that it leaves in "empty" rows where none of the items match both your conditions, so I used that "trick" to discard empty rows. For your generalized conditions try `n = 12;
t=Table[ a[i, j] == b[i, j], {j, 1,n - 2}, {i, 1,j - 5}]/.{}->Sequence[]`

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. That should be imposed.